# What's an alternative to the KitKat-People's app groups view in Lollipop's Contacts?

Tags: contacts, 5.0-lollipop, google-contacts, contact-groups

In Android KitKat's 'People' application I was able to access my contacts per group assigned, as shown below using my Nexus 5:

[image]

The new 'Contacts' application since the Android Lollipop upgrade does not appear to include this functionality. It's reported to Google in [issue #79803](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79803) and it appears lots of people are affected by this change.

What is an alternative to this? I'd really like to access my contacts again by their group.

Comment: FWIW; A Google employee mentioned today they're evaluating returning the groups functionality ([comment 501 in the issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79803#c501)).

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative option for users which can be found on the Play Store: [Contacts Groups for Lollipop](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flipdog.android.groups)

Answer (score -1):

According to this https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79803 the only workaround is to install a new Contacts app (like Contact+).

Hope Google will bring this feature back in a future update.

Comment: -1. You link to a page full of comments by lots of users of which most are only frustrated. Also, this bug report is already mentioned in my question. And I cannot believe there's no alternative contacts application in the Play Store with this functionality.